# Provably Secure FPEs vs Practically Used FPEs

Tags: provable-security, feistel-network, format-preserving

I have just checked a few FPE schemes like "Swap-or-not", "Mix-and-cut" which are provably secure. What techniques do the provably secure FPE scheme provably secure?

The FPE schemes used in practice use Feistel Network like FF1 and FF3. What makes provable secure FPEs work slower so that they are not used in practice?

Comment: I don't see that [swap-or-not](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.1176) has a level of security different from [FF1 or FF3-1](https://doi.org/10.6028/NIST.SP.800-38Gr1-draft); if that's the case, I want to know! [Mix-and-cut](https://doi.org/10.1007%2F978-3-642-40041-4_22) has a claim that I have not seen made by the three others: a bound for the adversary's advantage even when the number of previous queries gets to $N-2$. Caution: I'm out of my comfort zone for the detailed security claims of FPE schemes.